# Tracking motion of object (by itself or by colour)

Tags: google-project-tango

Is it possible to use the Google Tango Java API to track an object by itself (say, in the captured video feed I tap on the object and then the device tracks it continuously) or track an object by color (e.g. If I have a black sphere against a white background)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Tango API seems designed only to track the observer (i.e. the Tango tablet/phone), at present.  If you'd like to track other objects, I recommend using it with a library like OpenCV:

See:

- http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

You'll need some way of detecting or selecting an object, and then some way of tracking it:

- http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/df8/group__tracking.html